# Webview internal links

Tags: android, webview

I got a webview, that loads links. I got some Url , that they also contain other Url's  inside it. I was wondering if it is possible ,when user click on an url inside webview , that url to be loaded in another browser , not inside the webview??

Comment: can you share your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following code if the link is in you web site it will be opened inside the webview otherwise it will open a new browser:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.example.com")) {
        // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
        return false;
    }
    // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}});
```

For more info: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#AddingWebView