# Android Kotlin: How to load webpages inside or outside Webview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview

I have MainAdapter.kt that loads webpages using ShowLinkActivity.kt. I can load all webpages but some webpages get displayed inside Webview while others get displayed outside Webview. I want to make all webpages displayed either inside or outside Webview. How do I create that consistency?

[sample webpage displayed outside Webview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwRop.png)

[sample webpage displayed inside Webview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvEr6.png)

Below are my MainAdapter.kt and ShowLinkActivity.kt.

MainAdapter.kt:

```
class MainAdapter(val homeFeed: HomeFeed): RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        return homeFeed.News.count()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, position: Int): ViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
        val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(cellForRow)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val article = homeFeed.News.get(position)
        holder.view.title.text = article.title.replace("\n", " ")
        holder.view.description.text = article.description.replace("\n", " ")
        holder.view.publication_time.text = article.time.replace("\n", " ")

        holder.newsLink = article

    }

    class ViewHolder(val view: View, var newsLink: News? = null): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        companion object {
            val NEWS_LINK_KEY = "NEWS_LINK"
        }

        init {
            view.link_btn.setOnClickListener {
                var intent = Intent(view.context, ShowLinkActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra(NEWS_LINK_KEY, newsLink?.link)
                view.context.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }

    }

}
```

ShowLinkActivity.kt:

```
class ShowLinkActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_showlink)

        val news_link = intent.getStringExtra(MainAdapter.ViewHolder.NEWS_LINK_KEY)

        webViewId.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webViewId.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
        webViewId.settings.useWideViewPort = true

        webViewId.loadUrl(news_link.toString())
    }
}
```

Model classes:

```
class HomeFeed(val News: List<News>)
class News(val title: String, val description: String, val time: String, val link: String)
```

Comment: what do you mean? when click on links some display internally and some display externally or when loading pages from start-up this happens?

Comment: Hi CodeRanger, can you compare the 2 images attached? I meant that some webpages get displayed inside my webview layout in green while others get displayed outside on my webview layout.

Comment: I know that but what I mean is that when you click on a link this happens or when you first load a webpage?

Comment: If you encounter such problem when clicking on a link you can easily create a custom "WebViewClient" and override "shouldOverrideUrlLoading" method.

Comment: Thanks CodeRanger. Yes this happens when I click on a link. Can I ask you to write a Custom "WebViewClient" and override "shouldOverrideUrlLoading" method? I'm not familiar with this. Thank you.

Comment: Here is a similar question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30962986/webview-internal-links